# get list of ODBC data source in local pc using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, odbc

I'm looking for a way to get a list of ODBC data sources in local PC using PHP.
How can I achieve that?

Comment: Where does your PHP run, on the local machine or on a remote server?

Comment: Thanx Pekka for reply 

I'm working in local one 

regards

Comment: There is ODBC Support for PHP http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-connect.php, but I can't see a way to list available data sources in there. You may have to use a Windows program/command to get the list, and run `exec()` to fetch the results. But maybe something comes up here, just wait.

Comment: I have read this support manual before , but I didn't find what I need , anyway , thank u a lot

Answer (score 1):

If I assume that you're running on windows

User defined ODBC connections are stored under **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ODBC\ODBC.INI**

System defined ODBC connections are stored under **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI**

ODBC drivers are defined under **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI**

So you need some trick with php to read from registry like [this one](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_do_you_read_NT_registry_info_with_PHP) or [this one](http://pecl.php.net/package/win32std)

If I assume that you are on unix/linux then

User defined ODBC connections are stored under  **/etc/odbc.ini**

System defined ODBC connections are stored under **/home/username/.odbc.ini**

ODBC drivers are defined under **/etc/odbcinst.ini**

All of them are INI-like syntax text files.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has built-in connection support for MySQL so a ODBC connection is not required.  ODBC would be needed for any database environment not supported by PHP.

Answer (score 0):

```
    define('HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', 0x80000002); 
    $computer = '.'; 
    $reg = new COM("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\\\$computer\\root\\default:StdRegProv"); 
    $key_path = 'SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI'; 
    $sub_keys = new VARIANT(); 
    $reg->EnumKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, $key_path, $sub_keys); 

    foreach($sub_keys as $sub_key){ 
        echo $sub_key . "\n"; 
    }
```